# Настройка LAMP на VPS с 1 gb RAM

Tags: mysql, apache, vps, lamp

Прошу помощи с настройкой vps. Имеем vps от digitalocean - 1gb ram. На нем должны работать 100 сайтов wordpress с посещяемостью 10 человек в сутки на сайт (не дорвеи).

Настроил swap на 256 мб и имею следующие файлы конфигов:

`my.cnf`

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql-slow.log

max_allowed_packet=16M
key_buffer_size=8M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
join_buffer_size=40M
table_open_cache=1024
query_cache_size=40M
table_definition_cache=256
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=32M
max_connections = 300
query_cache_limit = 10M
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 3
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/


[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

`apache2.conf`

```
# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf.d
#   |   `-- *

# Global configuration
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 30
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      20
    ServerLimit         256
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>
# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
#User www-data
#Group www-data

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%b" bytes

Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
#Include sites-enabled/
```

Посоветуйте, какие параметры в какую сторону лучше изменить, в интернете нормальных конфигов для 1 gb ram не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx+PHP-FPM, причем PHP-FPM крайне желательно настроить в ondemand режиме, чтобы процессы почем зря не жрали память. А вообще, все сильно зависит от конкретной ситуации, универсального решения не будет.

Примерный конфиг пула PHP-FPM:

```
; Start a new pool named 'example'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('example' here)
[example]

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.$pool.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
;  ondemand - no children are created at startup. Children will be forked when
;             new requests will connect. The following parameter are used:
;             pm.max_children           - the maximum number of children that
;                                         can be alive at the same time.
;             pm.process_idle_timeout   - The number of seconds after which
;                                         an idle process will be killed.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm = ondemand

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 5

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 200

; Chdir to this directory at the start.
; Note: relative path can be used.
; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot
chdir = /
```